# Consolidate Multiple Select Results into One

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I accidentally deleted a database table and had to restore it from an outdated backup. I did something between the time I backed up and restored that changed the results I am receiving from a certain query. I want five results and it gives me seven because there are varying `Color` values for the resulting rows. Somehow before I had it working perfectly. Here's my SQL:

```sql
select LocationID, SUM(TransAmount) as TotalSales, DBAName, Color 
from dbx.dbo.SampleData 
group by LocationID, DBAName, Color
```

It used to give me:

```
LocationID      TotalSales  DBAName                Color
267529000000    7660.51     FASTWAY #1 TACO BELL   Red
267529000001    2681.801    FASTWAY #2 TACO BELL   Orange
267529000002    3020.57     FASTWAY #3 TACO BELL   Yellow
267529000003    3062.63     FASTWAY #4 TACO BELL   Green
267529000004    3401.36     FASTWAY #5 TACO BELL   Blue
```

But now with seemingly the same data it gives me:

```
LocationID      TotalSales  DBAName                 Color
267529000000    2183.26     FASTWAY #1 TACO BELL    Indigo
267529000000    2901.48     FASTWAY #1 TACO BELL    Red
267529000000    2575.77     FASTWAY #1 TACO BELL    Violet
267529000001    2681.80     FASTWAY #2 TACO BELL    Orange
267529000002    3020.57     FASTWAY #3 TACO BELL    Yellow
267529000003    3062.63     FASTWAY #4 TACO BELL    Blue
267529000004    3401.36     FASTWAY #5 TACO BELL    Green
```

It **always** had Indigo and Violet as colors but disregarded them and used Red as the main one. Any ideas? Tricks to get around this frustrating occurrence? Thanks!

Comment: You are grouping on `Color`, so it will give you a row for each color it finds (inside the groups already made by `LocationID` and `DBAName`). Note that if you do not group on `Color`, selecting `Color` will either not work or give you a pseudorandom value of the `Color` column inside the group (i.e. you can't rely on it always being 'Yellow').

Comment: What is your question?  Update the data so the color is always yellow, if that is what you think it should be for those rows.

Comment: i don't see how we can recreate your missing data except by adding a few "fake" entries to cause the same results.

Comment: for locationid : 267529000000    update the color to red ,you will get only 5 records ,later part of the question is not clear

Comment: We are not going to make you some updates to let your tables in perfect states. Ask if you need some help in code.

Comment: Is there a way to make the query only receive the first color it finds for those rows? Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not all clear what you want, but if it's just to have `Indigo`and `Violet`to count and show as `Red`you could use an inner query with a simple `CASE`statement to change the colors and then wrap it in an outer query where you do the aggregation and grouping. It will get the desired result:

```
SELECT LocationID, SUM(TransAmount) AS TotalSales, DBAName, Color 
FROM (
  SELECT LocationID, TransAmount, DBAName, 
    CASE Color 
     WHEN 'Indigo' THEN 'Red' 
     WHEN 'Violet' THEN 'Red' 
     ELSE Color END 
    AS Color 
  FROM dbx.dbo.SampleData 
) x
GROUP BY LocationID, DBAName, Color
```

However, it might not be a good solution.

EDIT: Another way that gets the first value found. Might not be good for performance though:

```
SELECT 
    s.LocationID, 
    SUM(TransAmount) AS TotalSales, 
    DBANAME_Color.DBAName, 
    DBANAME_Color.Color 
FROM dbx.dbo.SampleData s 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        LocationID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocationID ORDER BY DBAName) AS Row, 
        DBAName, 
        Color
    FROM dbx.dbo.SampleData 
) DBANAME_Color ON s.LocationID = DBANAME_Color.LocationID
WHERE DBANAME_Color.Row = 1 
GROUP BY s.LocationID, DBANAME_Color.DBAName, DBANAME_Color.Color
```

Comment: This is an effective solution however it is not very dynamic and I am wondering if there is a way to make only use the first color it finds for those rows?

Comment: @GabrielNahmias Please check my updated answer. There's probably better ways to accomplish what you want though.